# Intel Driver update utility

Tags: drivers

I am trying to run [the Intel Driver Update Utility](http://www.intel.com/support/detect.htm) but in Opera, Firefox and Chrome I get nothing, while in IE8 the pllugin is installed and when it runs it gives an error "" The NTVDM CPU has encountered an illegal instruction." ....

Anyone got this to work - or had similar problems?

Answer (score 2):

Try searching for Intel Driver update utility [here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Chipsets&ProductLine=Chipset+Software&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Matrix+Storage+Manager).

I think there is a standalone version which does not require a browser.

If you can elaborate on what are trying to do.. we may be able to guide you better.

Answer (score 2):

On my machine that Intel browser plugin requires Java installed. Did you install the latest Java runtime?

[Java Download](http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp)

The broadest standalone executable update for the **chipset** -- assuming your PC has an Intel chipset on it as many do -- can be downloaded here:

[Intel Download Centre](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Chipsets&ProductLine=Chipset+Software&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Chipset+Software+Installation+Utility)

Just pick an operating system and go.

If you need something else, like an Intel video driver, use the link Ganesh posted, or try to get Java working so the browser plugin works.